# The problems occurs when I follow the Acceleo Getting Started guidance in the wiki to generate java code from uml

Tags: acceleo

I spend several days to follow the Getting Started guidance in the wiki to generate java code from uml. I found some problems during the steps and failed to generate code.

This is the link of the guidance I followed: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Getting_Started.

The first question is: when I Right-click on the Acceleo module file (that is, the generate.mtl file) and select Run As > Launch Acceleo Application. I can’t find the uml model as show in the picture below, and also with the Target.

[image]

The second question is the problem shown in the acceleo.

[image: [enter image description here]

In case you can recurrent the problems, I’ll show you the version of eclipse and acceleo I use.

[image: [enter image description here]

Could you show me how to operate correctly to avoid these problems or is there any problems in my installation?
Thankyou!

Comment: regarding the first question, you have to create the uml metamodel yourself. This is the model thats actually converted to text. If you have and you still cant find it then just add the relative path yourself. The target path is where you want your target files to be placed when they are created... Follow https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Quick_Start, for a simple intro....

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion! I followed the quick start guidance, and some errors showed when I did the last step. It said "Couldn't load class org.eclipse.acceleo.module.hellowolrd.main.Generate from project org.eclipse.acceleo.module.helloworld","Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: org.eclipse.debug.core". Do you know why this happens?